# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 Error when adding new datasource

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm unable to add MySQL datasource in the latest ESB 4.8.1. With 4.8.0 it works fine.

Steps to reproduce:

- Download, Extract and startup latest ESB 4.8.1
- Goto: Configure -> Data Sources -> Add Data Source -> Fill required
  information and click Save.
- Following error appears:

  `Could not initialize class org.wso2.carbon.utils.i18n.Messages`

Stacktrace here. http://paste.opensuse.org/55128121

Comment: I have no problem configuring such a data-source in ESB 4.8.1
I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar and Sun JDK 1.6.0_32. What are your versions ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it now in other system and cannot reproduce it there so maybe it's related to java version or something. I don't have access to the system where the problem occurs so I'll have to check it later.

Comment: @user3100061 Your stack trace link no longer works.  Maybe you could include the stack trace in your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this seems to be fixed now. I downloaded the latest 4.8.1.zip package again and problem does not occur anymore. Just for curious I checked md5sum against the original package and the latest one and there was some difference so I believe WSO2 has re-deployed the release.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if your carbon.xml is missing the RegistryKeyStore element. If this error occurs, Add the following xml segment to your carbon.xml under `<Security>` element (as a sibling of `<KeyStore>` element)

```
    <RegistryKeyStore>
        <!-- Keystore file location-->
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <!-- Keystore password-->
        <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias-->
        <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
    </RegistryKeyStore>
```